# can not write data into file using c++

Tags: file, visual-c++

```
ofstream osCtrs("cts.txt",ios::out);
if (osCtrs.is_open()){
    for(unsigned ci = 0; ci < k; ci++){
        KMpoint& x =  ctrs[ci];
        for (unsigned di = 0; di < dim; di++)
        {
            //osCtrs << x[di];
            osCtrs << "what is happening?";
        }
    }
    osCtrs.close();
}
```

anything wrong?
file is created, but always empty,

Comment: Of course, your variable `k` or `dim` is < 0! But seriously, did you try to use a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me, given positive values for `k` and `dim`. Are you sure they're both non-zero? If either one is 0 or less, the program will never enter the inner loop where you're actually outputting stuff. Try setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to see what's happening.

Also, you don't need to specify `ios::out` for an `ofstream`, it's implied.

Comment: thank you, i can close this question now,
i think it is because this sentence does not work so well,
//osCtrs << x[di];
at first, "x "is float type, then i should use this :
osCtrs << fixed << setprecision(5) << x[di];

And maybe the comments does not work well, or the Compliler has memory!!! so even i commented the sentence, it still did not work.

Comment: Actually, if `dim` is an `int` smaller than zero, then `di < dim` will work in surprising ways. `dim` will convert to a large unsigned int; on VC++ it would be over 2 billion. The same logic applies to `k`